# Polymer - dynamic template rendering

Tags: javascript, polymer

is it somehow possible to render the template in a polymer element dynamically at runtime or when some light-dom elements are available?
I have the following situation:

```
index.html

<mega-menu>
  <span class="menuTriggerText">Open Menu</span>
  <ul class="test">
    <li>TEST1</li>
    <li>TEST2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="test">
    <li>TEST1</li>
    <li>TEST2</li>
  </ul>
</mega-menu>
```

in my polymer-element.html i want to do something as follows:

```
<template>
  <template repeat="{{temp}}"><p>I want to try this</template>
</template>

Polymer('mega-menu, {
  created:function(){},
  ready: function(){
    //getting markup from light-dom
    this.temp = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  },
  attached:function(){},
  detached: function(){},
  attributeChanged: function(attrName, oldVal, newVal){}
});
```

Now, my question is - how do i get this to work? do i need to bind something on my template? or do i need some kind of event-listener or observer on something?

Thanks, Gbeschbacher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely what [content insertion points](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/#toc-separation) are for. You can select top-level light DOM markup to render at specific locations in the Shadow DOM. `<content select=""></content>` takes a CSS selector and grabs nodes from the light DOM.

Your example would be:

```
<polymer-element name="mega-menu" noscript>
  <template>
    <content select=".test"></content>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

**You should not need to pry into the light DOM like this for such a simple case**, but for the sake of completeness, we *can* get your example working with a few important tweaks:

1. `document.getElementsByClassName('test')` looks for nodes in the entire document. This is not what you want. You only want children of `<mega-menu>`. Instead of `document` use `this` (e.g. `this.querySelectorAll('.test')`).
2. You're giving `<template repeat="{{temp}}">` a NodeList. It won't be able to stamp that out. It expects an Array. Something like `this.temp  = [].slice.call(this.querySelectorAll('.test'));` would work.

http://jsbin.com/balodowi/2/edit

Comment: I can't use the content insertion points because there are multiple divs which are getting wrapped around each <li> element - i totally forgot to mention that; i am working on a responsive multi-level push menu with custom-tags and polymer and hopefully it works soon :D your example with [].slice.call(...) worked perfectly fine - thx!