# How to do dynamic transclusion/child composition in Angular2?

Tags: angular, transclusion

I have the following *product details component* in which the user can type a product SKU. This SKU can be a book, digital product, drink, TV or a Game Console. Based on that SKU, the details will be shown. The SKU can belong to only one type.

The details component is composed of many different product type components. Instead of including all the child product type components in the details component, is it possible to inject the *child product type component* dynamically when the user enters the SKU and click *show details*?

Why I want to inject the child component is due to when a new product type like *microwave* is added, I just have to create that component and not modify the *product details* parent component.

```html
<product>
    <input [value]="productSKU" (input)="productSKU = $event.target.value">
    <button (click)="showProductDetails()">Show Product Details</button>
</product>
<details>
    <notfound></notfound>
    <book></book>
    <digital></digital>
    <drink></drink>
    <tv></tv>
    <gameconsole></gameconsole>
</details>
```

Comment: I'm wrestling with a similar use case myself. Have you looked into [DynamicComponentLoader](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b22eddf1cb1b958ddf9c3a64236fc3f3c80b9b0b/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.ts)? I've been playing around with it, yet to find a way of using it that feels right to me though...

Comment: Are there significant differences between each type of products? If not, you can make a generic `item` component, pass some `id` or `name` to it and load it dynamicallty as @drewmoore suggested

Comment: @EricMartinez suppose there *are* significant differences (or better yet, that we want to embed components of arbitrary type, perhaps implementing a given interface) - what would be the "Angular2 way" of doing that? Could you point me to somewhere in the google docs / github that might shed some light on what y'all are thinking w.r.t. dynamically bootstrapping components?

Comment: @drewmoore check out this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BTBHyMoq7P4qCv623ILN?p=preview). Type `SKU123` or `SKU456` to see it working (you can see those two data in `items.json`)

Comment: @drewmoore I have not looked into DynamicComponentLoader. The two possible solutions that I looked into are using (1) transclusion using **content** and (2) a dynamic child component which can be destroyed and added. There may be a few ways to hack it but want to know the non-frictional **angular2 way**. But for sure, I don't like the idea of using **ngShow** to show/hide the details based on the product type.

Comment: @EricMartinez As you may have noticed, these product types don't follow a object hierarchy. The other reason why I have many product types components is due to I can re-use those components in other parts of the application. These product types and it's properties are very different. For example the properties of *drink* and *gameconsole* are very different.I fear having a single component to manage all the product types (my own example) will violate the open/closed principle of SOLID. If a new product type is added, this top level component should not be modified.

Comment: @EricMartinez - super interesting plnkr, thanks. I'm hung up on the fact that the parent class still needs to know the selector (`generic-item`) the dynamically-loaded component will have... If the list had to display multiple items, each potentially having a different dynamic component, how would you modify this approach to enable that?

Comment: @EricMartinez's pnkr example is a solution to my question because my question was based on display only single product type.

Comment: @drewmoore Could you please explain your question with some sample view hierarchy and if possible create a new question? Looks like you are doing something interesting!

Comment: are you Looking for the <ng-content></ng-content>? which is alternate of transclusion of angular1.

Comment: In the Angular2 world, transclusion may not be right solution. It should be parent-child components composition and that should be dynamic.

Comment: In XAML, there is a [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx). I think something like a template selector would be a good solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polymer - dynamic template rendering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458340/polymer-dynamic-template-rendering)

Answer (score 0):

The Angular2 has [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html) which can create dynamic components.